# I cannot to take a photo when use video call with Twilio

Tags: video, twilio

I cannot  take a photo, record video when call video. Have any API help me get it. I am an android developer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the [Twilio Video API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) doesn't include photo functionality but here are some links describing how you can do this by accessing the HTML5 video object directly:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/04/capturing-html-5-video-to-an-image.aspx

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/07/uploading-captured-canvas-images.aspx

Recording is not available as of yet, but Video is only in beta right now.

In the meantime there are [3rd-party](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) client-side solutions which may work for your use case.

Hope this helps!